# How to copy multiple rows belonging to one id, and add to all of the others ids in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have table buses with unique IDs and a code:

```
| bus_id        | code        |
|:--------------|------------:|
| 1             |        A    |   
| 2             |        A    |   
| 3             |        A    | 
| 4             |        B    |  
| 5             |        B    |
```

Now for the bus_id I have these images with their ids in another table Images like this:

```
| image_id(not unique)| image_link | bus_id   | 
|:--------------------|-----------:|---------:|
| 1                   |     aaa.com|         1|   
| 2                   |     aab.com|         1|      
| 3                   |     aac.com|         4|    
| 4                   |     aad.com|         4|
```

How can I extend this image table, so that for each bus_id with the same code from the table buses, will create duplicate rows in the table images for all the buses in each bus code.

So the result I'm looking for with the examples above is:

```
| image_id(not unique)| image_link | bus_id   | 
|:--------------------|-----------:|---------:|
| 1                   |     aaa.com|         1|   
| 2                   |     aab.com|         1| 
| 1                   |     aaa.com|         2|   
| 2                   |     aab.com|         2|      
| 1                   |     aaa.com|         3|   
| 2                   |     aab.com|         3|
```

(As you can see, bus_id 1:3 all have the code A from table buses)

```
| 3                   |     aac.com|         4|    
| 4                   |     aad.com|         4| 
| 3                   |     aac.com|         5|    
| 4                   |     aad.com|         5|
```

(As you can see, bus_id 4:5 all have the code B from table buses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the images you need to add by generating all images and then filtering out the ones that exist.

I think this does what you want:

```
select b.bus_id, b.code, ii.image_id
from busses b join
     (select distinct i.image_id, b.code
      from images i join
           busses b
           on i.bus_id = b.bus_id
     ) ii
     on ii.code = b.code left join
     images i
     on i.bus_id = b.bus_id and i.image_id = ii.image_id
where i.image_id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I update the table with the result?

Comment: @WebOrNative . . . Add an `insert` before the `select` -- along with the appropriate columns.

Comment: Thank you, yes sorry I'm a complete beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Join the buses to themselves on the code so that for each bus of a code and each bus of the same code a pair exists. Then join the images on the second bus of the pairs. Now you can take the first bus in the pair and have the desired image information for it.

```
SELECT i1.image_id,
       i1.image_link,
       b1.bus_id
       FROM bus b1
            INNER JOIN bus b2
                       ON b1.code = b2.code
            INNER JOIN image i1
                       ON i1.bus_id = b2.bus_id;
```

To exclude the images that are already in the table, e.g. for inserting the missing ones, just add a `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated sub query that checks for the existence.

```
SELECT i1.image_id,
       i1.image_link,
       b1.bus_id
       FROM bus b1
            INNER JOIN bus b2
                       ON b1.code = b2.code
            INNER JOIN image i1
                       ON i1.bus_id = b2.bus_id
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM image i2
                                WHERE i2.image_id = i1.image_id
                                      AND i2.image_link = i1.image_link
                                      AND i2.bus_id = b1.bus_id);
```

So the `INSERT` would look like:

```
INSERT INTO image
            (image_id,
             image_link,
             bus_id)
SELECT i1.image_id,
       i1.image_link,
       b1.bus_id
       FROM bus b1
            INNER JOIN bus b2
                       ON b1.code = b2.code
            INNER JOIN image i1
                       ON i1.bus_id = b2.bus_id
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM image i2
                                WHERE i2.image_id = i1.image_id
                                      AND i2.image_link = i1.image_link
                                      AND i2.bus_id = b1.bus_id);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=8b7869ec49050086b72f21da96951dc2)